# Scrapy - How to scrape a website when access is denied [Lowes]

Tags: python, curl, web-scraping, scrapy

So I'm trying to create a webscraper for the Lowe's website and it seems the website does not allow the use of bots.

When running on scrapy shell I get: `twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError: User timeout caused connection failure:`

then I ran the command: `curl -v "https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-ZLINE-24-2-8-cu-ft-Dual-Fuel-Range-with-Gas-Stove-and-Electric-Oven-in-Stainless-Steel-and-Blue-Gloss-Door/5001835677?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-app-_-google-_-pla-_-186-_-soscooking-_-5001835677-_-0&placeholder=null&ds_rl=1286981&ds_rl=1286890&gclid=Cj0KCQjwgtWDBhDZARIsADEKwgO2jVgLDGJ3y9HjEm0yMpBhpji08IdDK_g1vODT42ZrVZ-kPm5aISYaAuHpEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds"`

which ended up with me getting denied from the website.

After some research I found that if I emulated being a 'real user' so I tried this (setting a location cookie)

```
headers={'Cookie': 'sn=2333;'}, #Preset a location
                meta={'dont_merge_cookies': True, #Allows location cookie to get through
                'url':url}
```

however this still got me the same error with timeout.

When loading in the website I checked the console:
[image]

but I'm also unsure of what I should look for or what to filter.
Is there any documentation or any tips anyone would have to emulate a real user using scrapy?

thanks for any help!

Comment: tried to use the exact same header from your browser.

Comment: @david the user agent right?

Comment: not only agent but all the header value and parameters

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was add user agents.

1.) Install rotating user agents:

```
pip3 install scrapy-useragents
```

2.) add in code to settings.py

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_useragents.downloadermiddlewares.useragents.UserAgentsMiddleware': 500,
}
# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
USER_AGENTS = [
    ('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '
     'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
     'Chrome/57.0.2987.110 '
     'Safari/537.36'),  # chrome
    ('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '
     'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
     'Chrome/61.0.3163.79 '
     'Safari/537.36'),  # chrome
    ('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) '
     'Gecko/20100101 '
     'Firefox/55.0'),  # firefox
    ('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '
     'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
     'Chrome/61.0.3163.91 '
     'Safari/537.36'),  # chrome
    ('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '
     'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
     'Chrome/62.0.3202.89 '
     'Safari/537.36'),  # chrome
    ('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '
     'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
     'Chrome/63.0.3239.108 '
```

'Safari/537.36'),  # chrome
]